# Unable to add additional column to an existing table in SpringBoot Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have been trying to modify my schema for some time now; by making changes to the model definition in SpringBoot.

I have also commndLineRunner which would populate the table with some sample data. For some Reason I have not been able to add Columns to my Existing Table.

I did execute an alter table command which is not reasonable and practical most times;( this solved the problem once; but I don't want to resort to this any more ).

I get the feeling this has more to do with the definition of the JPA properties in my SpringBoot MicroService. This looks like this :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=30
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

And this is the error that I am seeing when I execute my SpringBoot Application:

```
Hibernate: alter table if exists public.package_definition add column no_of_email_review_requests int4 not null

Error executing DDL "alter table if exists public.package_definition add column no_of_email_review_requests int4 not null" via JDBC Statement

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "no_of_email_review_requests" contains null values
```

This is the additional Column that I am trying to add into my Entity:

```
    private int noOfEmailReviewRequests;
```

Edit Sharing Entity Class:

```
@Entity
    @Data
    public class PackageDefinition {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private SubscriptionType type;
    private int noOfSMSReviewRequests;
    private int noOfFunnelPages;
    private Integer noOfEmailReviewRequests;
    }
```

Edit :

There seem to be 2 issues here, but both corresponding to the same table and the column addition/modification. I have renamed the following column in the table has been renamed:

```
no_review_requests to no_of_sms_review_requests --> this is throwing an error
```

And the folloing column has been added :

```
private Integer noOfEmailReviewRequests;
```

Comment: First of all I'd use Integer instead of primitive int. Then annotate your field as @Column(name="...", nullable=true)

Comment: share your entity class code..

Comment: @Joshgun tried it after changing it to Integer I still see the alter Table Exception.

Comment: I think that  "no_of_email_review_requests" contains null values is self explainatory

Comment: you added "nullable=true" ? @bhavs

Comment: @Joshgun yes I did that; this has left me quite stumpted. Looks Like either I drop the table so that a new one is created or write an SQL query to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At default configurations, You cannot add new column with `@NotNull` annotation, if you have any data at this table.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl=false` to your application.properties.
2. Add column and run without `@NotNull` annotation. After that, add `@NotNull` annotation to your entity.

I am not sure 2nd option but first one is totally working solution.

Edit: You can also define the new column with default value like `@Column(columnDefinition = "int default 100")`.

Answer (score 5):

You must set default value of non-null columnt for existing rows.

To do that use column definition

```
@Column(columnDefinition="COLUMN_TYPE default '0'")
```

where `COLUMN_TYPE` is SQL type of column of your choice.

or (Hibernate dependent)

```
@ColumnDefault(0)
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ColumnDefault.html